# Named Pipes - Broken Pipe Error When Buffer size Changes

Tags: c#, ipc, named-pipes

I working on creating a Named Pipe interface for one of my programs. I am following along with this tutorial:

http://jonathonreinhart.blogspot.com/2012/12/named-pipes-between-c-and-python.html

Everything is working great until the message from the python client changes from "Message [9]" to "Message [10]", which changes the buffer length. The python handles it well, but on the C# side, it fails here:

```
bw.Write((uint)buf.Length); <--------- Pipe shold have changed size here
bw.Write(buf);  <--------------------- Pipe Broken Error Here
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Your diagnostic makes very little sense.  You get a broken pipe when the other end got closed while you were writing.  You thus need to look at the other end for the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this is my first time working with named pipes so I will double check that and return with my findings.